# Unusual Mongo DB Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I need to do a special query. I have got an list of items availiable to do some Production. With this data I need to query the Documents where each type of item is in the List. A few (slightly) simplyfied Document looks may like this.

```
{

    "productname": "iron",
    "requirements": [
        {
            "ammount": 2,
            "item": "coal"
        },
        {
            "ammount": 2,
            "item": "ironore"
        }
    ],
}

{

    "productname": "coal",
    "requirements": [
        {
            "ammount": 2,
            "item": "wood"
        }
    ],
}

{

    "productname": "copper",
    "requirements": [
        {
            "ammount": 2,
            "item": "coal"
        },
        {
            "ammount": 2,
            "item": "copperore"
        }
    ],
}

{

    "productname": "Chair",
    "requirements": [
        {
            "ammount": 2,
            "item": "wood"
        },
        {
            "ammount": 2,
            "item": "nails"
        },
        {
            "ammount": 2,
            "item": "paint"
        }
    ],
}
{

    "productname": "Wooden Toy",
    "requirements": [
        {
            "ammount": 2,
            "item": "wood"
        },
        {
            "ammount": 2,
            "item": "paint"
        }
    ],
}
```

An example list may look like:
["wood", "beer","coal", "paint", "copperore"]

This should return the Documents of "Coal", "Copper" and "Wooden Toy", thus all of their requirements are in the List. For "Chair" the "nails" are missing and for "Iron" the "Ironore" is missing.

(Sorry for my bad english ;) )

Comment: Can you elaborate what is `special` and `unusual`?

Comment: I think it s unusual that not all parts of my query need to be matched but all requirements in the target documents needs to be fullfilled. Maybe I didn't explain it well enough.

Comment: So let's see if I understand: You have a list of requirements, let's say `[element1, element2, element4]`, and you want all the documents that have all these requirements? So for example they have `[element1, element2, element3, element4]`?

Comment: No, I have got a list with things in my storage, maybe 100 things or so. And I got MongoDB with things I can Produce, see the sample Documents above. Now I want to know what things can basically be produced. ( ammount can be ignored) So I want to get all documents which have all there Requirements listed in the Storage list.

Comment: So is it the other way around? if you have `[element1, element2, element3, element4]` in your store, you want documents that have `[element1, element2, element4]` as the requirements?

Comment: It would really help if you provided a set of example inputs and expected outputs that illustrate the possible cases (in the question itself, not as a comment).

Comment: @JohnnyHK You are Right... I will update it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) and [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) as a [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/cond)tion

```
var myList =  ["wood", "beer","coal", "paint", "copperore"]
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "requirements.item": { "$in":  myList } } },
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [ 
            { 
                "$setIsSubset": [ 
                    "$requirements.item", 
                    myList 
                ] 
            }, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE"
       ]
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

From your given documents, if you want to find the document that contains `requirements` with `coal` and `coppercore` then the following query:

```
> db.materials.find({"requirements.item" : "coal", "requirements.item": "copperore" }).pretty()
```

Would return:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("584990f083842cff8826d44f"),
        "productname" : "copper",
        "requirements" : [
                {
                        "ammount" : 2,
                        "item" : "coal"
                },
                {
                        "ammount" : 2,
                        "item" : "copperore"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: That is clear. But I want to get all Documents matching to a larger List.   There might be 50 items in my List and I want to get all Documents, that have only fullfilled requirements.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by _fullfilled requirements_

Comment: The target Documents have got a requirements array. Every item in this array needs to be listed in my "Availiable items" List in the Query. (maybe satisfy is a better word in this case)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly (which I'm not sure I do), you can use the [`all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all) operator:

```
db.materials.find({"requirements.item": {$all: ["coal", "copperore"]}})
```

Comment: No that would match all documents having coal and copperore in requirements. But in my case I have got a list [ "coal","copperore","bottle", "beer","nails" .....] And it needs to match all Documents which have ALL requirements satisfied. In this case this may be the documents for copper and beer. I do not exatly know what to query like in your example.